# How to remap union of strings to union of numbers?

Tags: typescript

From type:

```
type BeforeType = "1" | "2"
```

I would like to get a type:

```
type AfterType = 1 | 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not currently have support for a type function (let's call it `StringToNumber<T>`) that converts string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) representing numbers into their corresponding numeric literals.  I don't know if there are any open issues in GitHub asking specifically for this, but [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) requests the ability to do perform operations on numeric literals, which is fairly close (at least if you could do that you could probably write a decent `StringToNumber<T>` yourself).

There are various possible workarounds, but either they only work for hardcoded lists of numbers, or at best you can use [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) manipulation to represent non-negative whole numbers.  It is certainly not worth doing any of these things if you're looking at numbers like `"1"` and `"2"` though; any user-written implementation of `StringToNumber<T>` is going to be more complicated or fragile than just writing `1` and `2` yourself.

For example, here's a reasonably straightforward implementation of using [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to calculate `StringToNumber<T>` using tuples:

```
type StringToNumber<T extends `${number}`, R extends number[] = []> =
  T extends keyof R ? R[T] : StringToNumber<T, [...R, R['length']]>
```

And it totally works for `"1" | "2"` without a problem:

```
type NewAfterType = StringToNumber<"1" | "2">
// type NewAfterType = 1 | 2
```

But for TS4.4, it bails out for numbers bigger than ~40:

```
type Oops = StringToNumber<"100"> // error TS4.4
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite
```

And bad things happen with negative or non-whole numbers:

```
type Blah = StringToNumber<"-2"> // error 
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

type AlsoBlah = StringToNumber<"0.5"> // error
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite
```

I don't think it's worth it unless your use case is specifically dealing with small nonnegative whole numbers, and for those you can just write a lookup table:

```
type Nums = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
  40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
];
type StringToNumber<T extends Exclude<keyof Nums, keyof any[]>> = Nums[T]
```

So `StringToNumber<T>` is not provided and not easily achievable.

---

That being said, TypeScript *does* have the ability to do the reverse (let's call it `NumberToString<T>`) where you convert numeric literal types to their corresponding string literal types.  The implementation uses [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

```
type NumberToString<T extends number> = `${T}`;
```

So you can generate `BeforeType` from `AfterType` instead:

```
type NewBeforeType = NumberToString<AfterType>;
// type NewBeforeType = "1" | "2"
```

Depending on the use case, you might be able to refactor to start with numbers and end up with strings.  Or you could possibly write out both `BeforeType` and `AfterType` manually, and have the compiler *check* that `AfterType` corresponds to `BeforeType` by comparing `BeforeType` to `NumberToString<AfterType>`.  For example:

```
declare var checkConversion: BeforeType;
declare var checkConversion: NewBeforeType;
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// if there's an error here, it means you made a mistake
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQhBmB7AThAKuaBeKAiAjLlAD54BMuAUJaJFAILzATIZ074lRnW3QByAVwC2AIxZpEAZWDIAlgDsA5gB40UCAA9mCgCYBnKApHjkAPig4ABgBIA3mgC+VgNy9MUfhADucJKjZsTxMJaVlFVUZmVkwzNwB6eKg+Tx8-FHQPHAIiUlwKal0IAGMAGwBDVCgAN0qoYoALEoBrAGFEBWqWfTkOgC5YBAzAtyKyyuha5Hqm4raOruQe-tTfIYDMBKSAWl297YsAP2OT07PKRKg5eGSm1AByQ3KFDWRkFCg7iAAaK+AoYQQZ6GECIQQA8pFKDlAFyfTAcrNCDUBTlQH6MDlYrQABKJUESzkXSgdmoUGSHhk8mUkiEYhYag02ggekMtjsxnpyGcvxxTJ0BiMIWQAG0ALqWKDiixYSjk8nqLQCwxI0E3PkAfigOJFaAlAypEVpwrUvxFADpLTjeSL7qUWUpgA17mKxWYyRS6F5vFEJFkoIaaYg6aYVDkuPlcO7yZcUt7fTF2FBOKQeHLPdAAPKIMCGHCBpTGrlh-AABlLUaglxY72maCkABZzQ305dAlcFPDnsA5OUex0roYtNj9D0uqUQFAihAwNC9FAwIhR3JRBOO-BFHJmB6UjAKg1JQWi6HcNsKBZq28Pq2ku3FF2FD2+70XnCmSOxxA19PZ89dAulx6VdJ0UDcFC3ZF0xSehSn0RA93KA983CIMQwZXBS3NABWStL1rG8oDvTsEUfXt+1fIdNA-Ikv0nH853-Rdl2A9dN23ShHHcL0RDzKV01LX58F+MhfgAZl+Btfiw34ADZfgAdl+AAOX4AE5BIE5MhOTETk3E5NJOTaTkzk5NFOTFTk3U9MyE0shtLIXSyH0shDLIYyyFMshzLISyyHUqBRM00TtNE3TRP00TDNE4zRNM0TzNEyzROs8kG00httIbXSG30htDIbYyG1MhtzIbSyG1UygxTcFIj2DE1FWZVkoAAUSo0pBCKFRVUQG46X0X5epuZ4QGlGVgmEfRdTFLiBB8BN22Q6lCwa4twzyc8LiSOMFqYP0kxTbgaA8bNc0PFDVrQ5AS3LXCkhra9d33C6VuPdCz3u15aygE66BguCEKQgNLvem6MOwr7HuQSggA)